# How to create, solve and plot conditional function in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, plot, conditional-statements

For example,
I have a

```
f(x)=
    9+4(x+3), if -4<=x<-1 (subf1)
    7-9(x-0.4), if -1<=x<1 (subf2)
```

How can I create a function of f(x) in matlab?
I tried

```
f=0
syms x
f=f+ subf1 with heaviside+ subf2 with heaviside
```

But I cannot give a `v` to solve `f(v)` and I cannot plot `f(x)` only from `-4` to `1`.
So is there another way to write conditional function?

Sorry my description is a little hard to follow. If you don't understand what I am asking, please let me know and I will try to rephrase. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do with it. If for some reason you need symbolic, here is one way to write your [symbolic function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symfun.html):

```
syms x
f1 = (9 + 4 * (x + 3)) * heaviside(x + 4) * (1 - heaviside(x + 1));
f2 = (7 - 9 * (x - 0.4)) * heaviside(x + 1) * (1 - heaviside(x - 1));
f = symfun(f1 + f2, x);
```

Otherwise, you can [write your function in a file](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-functions-in-files.html) as:

```
function out = f(x)
out = (9 + 4 * (x + 3))*(x>=-4)*(x<-1) + (7 - 9 * (x - 0.4))*(x>=-1)*(x<1);
```

Or you can define it as an [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html):

```
f = @(x) (9 + 4 * (x + 3))*(x>=-4)*(x<-1) + (7 - 9 * (x - 0.4))*(x>=-1)*(x<1);
```

Then, you can plot any of the functions using, for instance, [`fplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fplot.html):

```
fplot(f, [-4, 1])
```